# Return Multiple Column Names from a table in one cell where value is present

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel table where I calculate the total number of machine parts required in a large-scale manufacturing operation. Each row represent a different machine parts and each column after some description of the machine part represents a machine number. The same machine part may or may not be used in multiple machine numbers. I have a "Machine Numbers" column where I would like to return all the Column Names where a value is present. As in, if that machine part is required in the Machine Numbers MN1, MN3 and MN10, it should return "MN1, MN3, MN10". I have posted the table image below for further clarification with some example answers on the red column:

[image: Example]

I have done it manually. What formula should I write so that the Machine Numbers column fills up automatically? Please note that this is a TABLE. Let's assume the table name is "MP". I also use Excel 265.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, FILTER(MP[[#Headers],[MN1]:[MN5]],MP[@[MN1]:[MN5]]<>""))`

The `FILTER` selects all column headers where there are - per row - values (using [Implicit intersection operator @](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34)

`TEXTJOIN` combines the result to a string.

Comment: By the way, is there any way to do it where it would automatically update if I add more columns? Sometimes, there might be 50 to 60 machines.

Comment: it will update if you add the machine inbetween the columns. You could add a dummy column at the end of the table (and include this to the formula) - If there are new machines, insert them to the left of the dummy column

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks a lot!